# StratifiedKFold split train and validation set size

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation, k-fold

I am using `StratifiedKFold` and I am not sure what is the training and test size returned by `kfold.split` in my code below. Assuming `Print(array.shape)` returns `(12904, 47)` i.e number of rows are 12904 and number of columns are 47, what would be the training and test size?

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=8)

for train, validation in kfold.split(X, Y):
            # Fit the model
            model.fit(X[train], Y[train])
            # predict probabilities for training set
            predicted = model.predict(X[train])

            predicted_report = classification_report(Y[train], predicted)
            print(predicted_report)
            # accuracy: (tp + tn) / (p + n)
            accuracy = accuracy_score(Y[train], predicted)#accuracy_score(Y[train], yhat_classes)
```

Comment: 4/5 th & 1/5th of 12904? since `n_splits=5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already hinted in the comments, your training set size will be `(n_splits-1)/n_splits`, and your validation set size wil be `1/n_splits` of the size of your initial data, i.e. here 4/5 and 1/5, respectively.

Here is a simple reproducible demonstration using the iris data and `n_splits=5`, as in your case:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
print(X.shape) # initial dataset size
# (150, 4)

kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=8)

for train, validation in kfold.split(X, y):
            print(X[train].shape, X[validation].shape)
```

The result of which is:

```
(120, 4) (30, 4)
(120, 4) (30, 4)
(120, 4) (30, 4)
(120, 4) (30, 4)
(120, 4) (30, 4)
```

So, to check for yourself in your data, you just need to add the above `print` statement in your for-loop.